# How to do transformation from one DataFrame to create a new DataFrame with different format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Now I have a DataFrame `TrainLabelModified`, a `120538 x 3` DataFrame as below:

```
        user_id  video_id  operation_times
0             0        10                3
1             0        15                3
2             0        19                7
3             0        21                3
4             0        28                5
5             0        30                9
6             0        39                3
7             0        40                3
8             0        45                3
9             0        47                2
10            0        58                3
...         ...       ...              ...
120526     5048         7                1
120527     5048        37                2
120528     5048        40               12
120529     5048        49                2
120530     5048        52                6
120531     5049         3               49
120532     5049        25               14
120533     5049        35               21
120534     5049        36                1
120535     5049        37                4
120536     5049        46               25
120537     5049        53               10
120538     5049        56                5
```

And I want a new DataFrame `TrainDataFinal`, a `5050 x 64` DataFrame like this:

```
        user_id  video_0_operation_times v1_ot v2_ot ... v61_ot  v62_dt  
0             0        ...                 ...  ...       ...      ...
1             1        ...                 ...  ...       ...      ...
2             2        ...                 ...  ...       ...      ...
3             3        ...                 ...  ...       ...      ...
4             4        ...                 ...  ...       ...      ...
5             5        ...                 ...  ...       ...      ...
...         ...        ...                 ...  ...       ...      ...
5048       5048        ...                 ...  ...       ...      ...
5049       5049        ...                 ...  ...       ...      ...
```

For example, for `user 0` in sample data, his/her `v(n)_ot` is: `v10_ot` = 3, `v15_ot` = 3, `v19_ot` = 7, ... , `v58_ot` = 3 and other `v(n)_ot` = 0.

My idea is to create a `TrainDataFinal = np.zeros([5050,64])` and assign value to it one by one according to `TrainDataModified`. But since the DataFrame is quite huge, it might cost too much time. Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: So, you want a `pivot` operation.

Comment: `df.pivot(index='user_id', columns='video_id')`

Comment: @Vinnton read this  from piRsquared https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe/47152692#47152692 you will understand pivot better

Comment: @COLDSPPED Unfortunately I got an error: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`. Is there anything I can to fix the error?

Comment: @Bharath Thanks a lot!

Comment: Okay, try this - `df.pivot_table(index='user_id', columns='video_id', values=operation_times')`